# Django Password-Reset Custom Template not working

Tags: python, html, django

I want to use Django's built-in `PasswordChangeView` to let users reset their passwords. My `PasswordResetView` and my `PasswordResetDoneView` are working.

Django always give me the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /reset
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with keyword arguments
  '{'uidb64': 'MTM', 'token': '549-1f211ad25c6d91e420a4'}' not found.
  1 pattern(s) tried: ['password_change/$']
```

I already tried to add:

```
path(
    'password_change/',
    auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView,
    {"template_name": "authenticate/reset/password_change.html"},
    name="password_reset_confirm"),
```

but that didn't change anything.

My urlpatterns:

```
path(
    'reset',
    auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='authenticate/password/reset/reset.html'),
    {
        'template_name': 'email/test.html',
        'html_email_template_name': 'email/test.html',
        'email_template_name': 'email/test.txt',
        'subject_template_name': 'email/test.txt',
    },
    name='password_reset'),
path(
    'reset/done',
    auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
        template_name='authenticate/password/reset/done.html'),
    name='password_reset_done'),
path(
    'password_change/',
    auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView,
    {"template_name": "authenticate/password/reset/confirm.html"},
    name="password_reset_confirm"),
path(
    'password_change/',
    auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView,
    {"template_name": "authenticate/password/reset/complete.html"},
    name="password_reset_complete"),
```

Comment: Last url pattern is wrong - confirm has different pattern. Looks like resulf of CTRL-C+CTRL-V.

Comment: Thank you I changed it but it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the docs about [`PasswordResetConfirmView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView) you can see:

> Keyword arguments from the URL:
>
> - **uidb64**: The user’s id encoded in base 64.
> - **token**: Token to check that the password is valid.

So that means that you need to change your URL from

```
path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView ...
```

to something similar to this

```
path('password_change/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView ...
```

You will have to figure out the exact format that works for you, but this should point you in the right direction.